# Laravel 5 - How do I return a oneToMany relationship?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm new to Laravel, and using Laravel 5 i'm having trouble returning an array from my database.

I have several "acts", and each act has many "banners". Whenever I try to get output from my array of banners ( **$act->banners->count()** ), i find it throws an error because it is null.

Here is the code:

routes.php:

```
Route::model('banners', 'Banner');
Route::model('acts', 'Act');

// Controller routes
Route::resource('acts', 'sf_ActController');
Route::resource('acts.banners', 'sf_BannerController');


Route::bind('banners', function($value, $route) {
    return App\Banner::whereact_id($value)->first();
});
Route::bind('acts', function($value, $route) {
    return App\Act::whereact_id($value)->first();
});
```

Act.php (model)

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Act extends Model
{
protected $table = 'sf_act';
protected $primaryKey = 'act_id';

public function act() {
      return $this->hasMany('Banner');

    }
}
```

Banner.php (model)

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Banner extends Model
{

  protected $table = 'sf_banner';
  protected $primaryKey = 'banner_id';

  public function banner() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Act' , 'act_id' , 'act_id');
  }
}
```

sf_ActController.php (controller)

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Act;
use App\Banner;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Input;
use Redirect;

class sf_ActController extends Controller
{
  public function show(Act $act)
  {

  //pass object to correct view
  return view('pages.acts.show' , compact('act'))->with('banner', Banner::find($act));
  }
```

acts/show.blade.php (view)

```
<!-- /resources/views/acts/show.blade.php -->
@extends('app')

@section('content')
<h2>{{ $act->act_title }}</h2>

  {{ $act->banners->count() }}
```

at this point I get the following error:

> FatalErrorException in a03036ad81fb4e6d90e9fe5e3da62c65 line 7:
>   Call to a member function count() on null

Why am I not fetching my banner data!? (The title variable in the h2 tags outputs fine, so the db and everything up until that point is working.)Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the complete "route" to the model in the relationships **including the namespace**:

```
public function act() {
  return $this->hasMany('App\Banner');

}
```

And the same on belongsTo:

```
public function banner() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Act' , 'act_id' , 'act_id');
}
```

Could be a good idea to include the name of the foreign kay in the hasMany method.

```
public function act() {
  return $this->hasMany('App\Banner', 'act_id');

}
```

Also possibly you don't need to include the third parameter in the belongs to.

Hope it helps. Also can share with you a link to learn about Laravel step-by-step: [Learn Laravel 5.0 => 5.1](https://www.udemy.com/laravel-5-course-learn-php-laravel/?couponCode=forum)

Comment: Thank you, you are absolutely right! There was also another problem which was pointed out by the answer below, a function with the wrong name... once those two things were fixed it worked perfectly! I couldn't have done it without your help!

Comment: Great! I'm glad it helps. Best wishes.

Answer (score 1):

You currently have your `hasMany` relationship setup like this:

```
public function act() {
  return $this->hasMany('Banner');

}
```

However in your view your calling this relationship:

`$act->banners->count()`

Shouldn't it be:

`$act->act()->count();`

Comment: Thank you. Your comment helped me figure it out. I had named the functions incorrectly! '$act->banner->count()' was correct, but you can see in my "Act" model above that the function which is named "Act" refers to the "banner" part. What a mess! Once I had fixed that and the namespacing from the answer above it worked! I really appreciate the help.

Comment: Glad I could help! Happy coding :)